# Why do we call super() in constructor

Tags: java, constructor, super

We have a constructor like this:

```
public statusArea()     
{           
   super();         
   add(pageIdentifier);     
}
```

Why do we call `super` in it?

Comment: Possibly "we" add the call because "we" don't understand that it is redundant :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to specify the constructor to call if:

You want to call a superclass constructor which has parameters

You want to chain to another constructor in the same class instead of the superclass constructor

Answer (score 5):

From [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

> With super(), the superclass no-argument constructor is called. With
> super(parameter list), the superclass constructor with a matching
> parameter list is called.
>
> Note: If a constructor does not explicitly
> invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler automatically
> inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass. If
> the super class does not have a no-argument constructor, you will get
> a compile-time error. Object does have such a constructor, so if
> Object is the only superclass, there is no problem.

Answer (score 3):

`super()` invokes the parameterless constructor of the super class.

In your code it makes no difference, since the compiler will add `super()` implicitly if you don't. In general, you add an explicit call to the super class's constructor if you wish to call a specific constructor of the super class.

Comment: I think this answer is incomplete without the explanation that every class in Java extends from Object and the call to super for a class that does not extend any class directly translates to a call to the no arg constructor of Object. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Invocation of a superclass constructor must be the first line in the subclass constructor.

The syntax for calling a superclass constructor is

```
super(); // the superclass no-arg constructor is called
```

or:

```
super(params);//the superclass constructor with a matching params is called
```

Note:

> If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass. If the super class does not have a no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error. Object does have such a constructor, so if Object is the only superclass, there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the `super` keyword in Java is to allow you to access the instance fields, instance methods or the constructor of a super class from which a class extends.

Since every class in Java extends from `Object` implicitly, a call to `super()` in a constructor for a class that does not `extend` from any class means a call to the no-arg constructor in the `Object` class.

Even if you don't put the `super()` call explicitly in a constructor, the compiler will add one.

Answer (score 1):

Here you use `super()` to give the parent class (ie. the class which this one extends) a chance to initialize any fields or variables, so that your sublcass can work correctly. For example, the superclass may have some fields or variables which you do not use in your subclass, but which are needed for the class to work correctly.

In this case, `super()` invokes the parameterless constructor of the superclass, ie. the one which your class extends.

If you call `super(...)` with parameters, then the superclass constructor with the matching parameters is called.

As others have said, if you don't call `super()` yourself, the compiler will call it.